# How to Set & Focus the last input text once user finishes typing from the 1st input text

Tags: javascript

I have multiple input text inside a table. How can I automatically set value & focus the last input text once I'm done typing values from the 1st input text box?

```
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
```

my js code:

```
var d =  id('my_table', document); 
for (var x=1; x<d.rows.length; x++) {                    
    d.rows[x].cells[12].firstChild.innerText = x;                   
    d.rows[x].cells[12].firstChild.focus();     
}
```

Comment: How do you define that you have done typing in first box?

Comment: How will you know that user has finished typing in first input ?

Comment: `blur` might be useful or `keyup` or `keydown`

Comment: when user click on the second box

Comment: `d.rows[x].cells[12].firstChild` <-- This is the type of code that makes me cringe.  This type of code is very fragile and breaks as soon as you change the dom slightly.  Ideally you should add a class to the inputs you wish to select and and query them directly.

Comment: use `keypress` event listener... but like everyone above me is saying, what will you define as when the user has finished typing, you could set a timing `setTimeout()` that runs after keypress and if a key hasn't been pressed in `x` amount of time then `.focus()` but really you need to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `blur` event or the `keypress` event (to handle that the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or a combination of both:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#table input');
inputs[0].addEventListener('blur', setFocus);
inputs[0].addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 13)
     setFocus();
});

function setFocus() {
  inputs[inputs.length - 1].value = '123';
  inputs[inputs.length - 1].focus();
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
   <tr><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>  
   <tr><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>  
   <tr><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer and without resorting to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, It the same as your want but its helps you, try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td> <input type="text" maxlength="4" tabindex="1" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" maxlength="4" tabindex="3" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" maxlength="4" tabindex="4"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text" maxlength="4" tabindex="2" /> </td>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("input").on('input',function () {
    if(jQuery(this).val().length == jQuery(this).attr('maxlength')) {
        nextinput = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('tabindex'))+1;
        // Here you can take current input value and set where you want
        jQuery("input[tabindex="+nextinput+"]").focus();
    }
});
</script>
```